# serializeArray observation with ID and Name attributes

Tags: jquery, forms, serializearray

I've noticed that if you ***exclude*** a *Name* and *ID* from a form element serializeArray will not return it's value. Is this correct/by design? Just curious...

```
<form id="myForm" name="JimTheForm">
  <input type="text" value="serializeArray doesn't see me" />
  <input id="someID" name="someName" type="text" value="serializeArray sees me!" />
</form>
```

in this example the first text field will not be included in serializeArray() but the second text field will because it has a *name* and *id*, i think???

Comment: Every `input` element must have a name, so your invalid code is being ignored.

Comment: This is good to know. I don't want serializeArray to pickup this information. Thanks for the info!

Comment: I up voted you because this is a good question. I dislike it when people down vote because they probably think that it is a simple/ dumb question. What's so bad about it. good information was emitted.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [`.serializeArray() API Documentation`](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/) :

> The .serializeArray() method uses the standard W3C rules for
>   successful controls to determine which elements it should include; in
>   particular the element cannot be disabled and must contain a **name**
>   attribute.

So, having the **name** attribute is a must for `.serializeArray()`.